# option delimiter in cut

Tags: command-line, cut-command

I want to know if it is possible with the cut option to indicate the delimiter with a line break "\n" or "\t".

Ex: `cut -f 1 -d "\t"`. This line gives me error.

Answer (score 3):

Unlike with e.g. `tr`, you cannot pass `\t` or `\n` directly to `cut`. You need [ANSI-C quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) style.

You can use `$'\n'` or `$'\t'` as delimiter.
Note, that `tab` is the default delimiter for `cut`, so you can omit setting the delimiter.

Comment: thank you @pLumo, I had read the command help but it was not very clear to me